# Promise Function not return error in Angular 6

Tags: angular

```
  Call(apiurl, model) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.adminService.add<any>(apiurl, model).toPromise().then(res => {
               return resolve({
                    'error': false,
                    'data': res
                });
            }), error => {
                return reject({
                    'error': true,
                    'data': error
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my function.
When I call this function and API response is 200 Ok response then it's return response but when error t throw by API then it does not return an error

```
public add<T>(APIpath, data): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.post<T>(apiPath, data);
}
```

This is my generic Function Which is used in call Function for call API

```
this.Result = await this.Call("API Path", Model);
```

This is code of calling this function and I Want to store response in this Result Variable

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the wrong placement of error block. You could alter your code as below to make it work. Hope you are using `TypeScript`

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    return this.adminService.add<any>(apiurl, model).toPromise().then(res=>{
        resolve({
            'error': false,
            'data': res
        })
    }).catch(error=>{
        resolve({
            'error': true,
            'data': error
        }) 
    });
});
```

Please note the `catch` block and removed `return` statements.

Comment: This is also not Return value in a variable

Comment: @RajuGiri For getting the value in your variable, you need to resolve it. Please see the edited answer.
So both will resolve the promise. Why we are resolving it even in case error, is that, we don't have a catch block in `add` function.

Please let me the results.